# HTTP Post in ionic 4 not going through to web service

Tags: angular, web-services, http, ionic-framework

I have the following method within my register.page.ts file within my ionic 4 project. This executes whenever i click the submit button on my register.html form.

```
register(form) {
this.authService.register(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
});
}
```

this method calls this method with my auth.service.ts file.

```
register(postData: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`https://1146c1fe.ngrok.io/register`,  
(postData)).pipe(
  tap(async (res: AuthResponse ) => {
    if (res.Success) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  })

);
```

}

this is used to register a new user through a web service that be created. 
I have the following authresponse.ts interface to store info iobtained from the server.

I am unsure how this interface should look. I only wish to receive a yes or no from the server to determine if the user may register or not.

The web service

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {  
const user = req.body;   
const passwordPromise = util.promisify(bcrypt.hashSync);
const pass = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);
let success = true;

createUser(user.name, user.email, pass, [], (err) => {
    if (err){
        success = false;
        res.send(success);
    }
});

res.end(success);
});
```

I would like to know when a success has been sent and would then like to load a new page called tabs. Any advice on how to achieve this. So at the the moment i can connect to the server and a user is created but I receive no response from the server or i am unsure on how to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing register to the following using `map` RxJS operator instead of `tap`. [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) is used to transform a response, in this case coercing to a truthy or falsy value. [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) isn't used for transformation, but instead side effects:

```
register(postData: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
  return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`https://1146c1fe.ngrok.io/register`, postData)
    .pipe(
      map((res: AuthResponse) => !!res.Success)
    );
}
```

That being said, you may need to share the definition of `AuthResponse`. Based on the your server code it looks like you are simply sending back a simple boolean, rather than an object that has a property `Success`. You may want to update your question and log out the exact response from the server because that will definitely change how `map` is used. You can actually add something like `tap(response => console.log(response))` inside `pipe()` before `map` to see what's being received.

You should really consider sending back some sort error status code like 4xx or 5xx so that you can simply use the success/error callbacks of `subscribe()` to easier manage handle success vs error in your component consuming this service.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That does help alot. I was unsure on how to check what the server is returning to me but this will help me a lot. Thank you very much

Comment: tap(response => console.log(response)) inside pipe()